# QRCODE with multiples values

Tags: qr-code

I want to create an app(android and iOS) that can Scan QRCode with multiples values and print results(those values).

I have done it like this:

> QRCODE to generate: (for test)

```
FirstName:abderrahmane;LastName:Aitbaali
```

I have used `:` and `;` characters to separate values

the question is, if I'm on the right way of using QR Code best practices.

Comment: Thought of converting JSON to QR ? What you propose works, but you need to be alert for escaping the separators (colon semi-colon). JSON has  a bit more overhead, but you are more future proof (if things data structure changes).

Comment: Some thing like that. what people do when they want to put multiples values on QR?. if there is some standards to do so.